# turn off axis, keep ticks

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I am plotting an image using plt.imshow() using the seaborn add on....

```
from astropy.io import fits
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set_style(style='white') #turn off grid

def plotter():
    mapy = np.zeros((100,100))
    pf = 2.8 #my physical pixel size
    areaX = mapy.shape[0]/2*pf # half of the area!
    areaY = mapy.shape[1]/2*pf # half of the area!
    cmapz ='Reds'
    fig = imshow(mapy,interpolation='spline16',origin='lower',cmap=cmapz,extent=[-areaX*pf,areaX*pf,-areaY*pf,areaY*pf])
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.show()
```

I now want to get rid off the ugly axis around my plot, but **KEEP** the ticks in place as they refer to the distance.
Everything I found and tried, e.g. `plt.axis('off')`, `fig.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)`, `plt.tick_params(top='off', bottom='on', left='off', right='off', labelleft='on', labelbottom='on')`  etc. turns off both the axis **AND** the ticks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may decide not to use seaborn and turn the axes spines invisible:

```
for d in ["left", "top", "bottom", "right"]:
    plt.gca().spines[d].set_visible(False)
```

```css
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mapy = np.random.rand(100,100)
pf = 2.8
areaX = mapy.shape[0]/2*pf # half of the area!
areaY = mapy.shape[1]/2*pf # half of the area!

fig = plt.imshow(mapy,interpolation='spline16',origin='lower',
                 cmap='Reds',extent=[-areaX*pf,areaX*pf,-areaY*pf,areaY*pf])
plt.grid(False)

for d in ["left", "top", "bottom", "right"]:
    plt.gca().spines[d].set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

[image]

The same can be done, using rcParams,

```
s = {"axes.spines.left"   : False,
    "axes.spines.bottom" : False,
    "axes.spines.top"    : False,
    "axes.spines.right"  : False}
plt.rcParams.update(s)
```

```css
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
s = {"axes.spines.left"   : False,
"axes.spines.bottom" : False,
"axes.spines.top"    : False,
"axes.spines.right"  : False}
plt.rcParams.update(s)

mapy = np.random.rand(100,100)
pf = 2.8
areaX = mapy.shape[0]/2*pf # half of the area!
areaY = mapy.shape[1]/2*pf # half of the area!

fig = plt.imshow(mapy,interpolation='spline16',origin='lower',
             cmap='Reds',extent=[-areaX*pf,areaX*pf,-areaY*pf,areaY*pf])
plt.grid(False)

plt.show()
```

Alternatively you can set the axes edgecolor to transparent.

```
plt.rcParams["axes.edgecolor"]=(1,1,1,0)
```

```css
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams["axes.edgecolor"]=(1,1,1,0)

mapy = np.random.rand(100,100)
pf = 2.8
areaX = mapy.shape[0]/2*pf # half of the area!
areaY = mapy.shape[1]/2*pf # half of the area!

fig = plt.imshow(mapy,interpolation='spline16',origin='lower',
             cmap='Reds',extent=[-areaX*pf,areaX*pf,-areaY*pf,areaY*pf])
plt.grid(False)

plt.show()
```

Or, if you want to use seaborn (and it's white-style), additionally reactivate the ticks using

```
plt.tick_params(axis="both", which="major", length=5)
```

```css
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set_style(style='white') #turn off grid

mapy = np.random.rand(100,100)
pf = 2.8
areaX = mapy.shape[0]/2*pf # half of the area!
areaY = mapy.shape[1]/2*pf # half of the area!

fig = plt.imshow(mapy,interpolation='spline16',origin='lower',
                 cmap='Reds',extent=[-areaX*pf,areaX*pf,-areaY*pf,areaY*pf])
plt.grid(False)

for d in ["left", "top", "bottom", "right"]:
    plt.gca().spines[d].set_visible(False)

plt.tick_params(axis="both", which="major", length=5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

As @mwaskom points out in the comments, Seaborn also offers `sns.despine()` to get rid of the spines, which you would then call like

```
sns.despine(left=True, top=True, bottom=True, right=True)
```

Note the double negation (**de**spine True means not to have spines).

```css
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set_style(style='white') #turn off grid

mapy = np.random.rand(100,100)
pf = 2.8
areaX = mapy.shape[0]/2*pf # half of the area!
areaY = mapy.shape[1]/2*pf # half of the area!

fig = plt.imshow(mapy,interpolation='spline16',origin='lower',
             cmap='Reds',extent=[-areaX*pf,areaX*pf,-areaY*pf,areaY*pf])
plt.grid(False)
sns.despine(left=True, top=True, bottom=True, right=True)

plt.tick_params(axis="both", which="major", length=5)
plt.show()
```

Comment: If using seaborn `despine` will actually remove the spines but not the ticks (different from turning the axis off).

Comment: @mwaskom But since the ticks are removed by the seaborn-white style, one has to turn them on again, right?

Comment: Oh, well, sure, one should use the `ticks` style if they want ticks!

Comment: (technically `white` doesn't turn ticks "off" which can't be done, it just sets their length to 0).