# Cannot remove axis spines when using cartopy projections in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I have been using cartopy with matplotlib in python 2.7 to visualize some data on maps. But, when I try to remove the axes spines (top and right ones) with the following code snippet:

```
ax1.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax1.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
```

It wouldn't work. Setting the spine thickness doesn't work as well:

```
 ax1.spines['left'].set_linewidth(3)
 ax1.spines['bottom'].set_linewidth(3)
```

The above lines of code do not have an effect on the plots when I am using a cartopy projection. But if I use the regular matplotlib axes, they work fine.
I have tried the rcParams method mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44525032/turn-off-axis-keep-ticks) as well with no avail.
I am including the stripped down version of my code below:

```
lons=np.arange(10, 50, .5)
lats=np.arange(7, 44, .5)

xticks=np.arange(math.ceil(lons.min()),
        math.floor(lons.max())+4, 4)
yticks=np.arange(math.ceil(lats.min()),
        math.floor(lats.max())+4, 4)

fig=plt.figure()    
ax1=fig.add_subplot(111,
        projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())

ax1.set_extent([lons[0], lons[-1],
        lats[0], lats[-1]],
        crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax1.coastlines()

ax1.set_xticks(xticks)
ax1.set_yticks(yticks)

ax1.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax1.spines['right'].set_visible(False)

ax1.spines['left'].set_linewidth(3)
ax1.spines['bottom'].set_linewidth(3)  
plt.show()
```

I am using miniconda to manage the packages and the version of the relevant modules used are as follows:

```
Python - 2.7.16
matplotlib - 2.3.3
cartopy - 0.17.0
```

So, how can I remove those spines when using cartopy projections?

> **UPDATE**

I dig deeper and found these:
[frameon=False does not remove map frame](https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/829)
[Cannot change the border width of the cartopy axes](https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/1077) 
Which are related to my problem. From the information on those posts I have come up with a workaround for my problem:
First, you have to turn off the axes, or the spines, with the following code.

```
ax1.outline_patch.set_visible(False)
```

Then you can use *axis.spines['']* method to turn on individual spines like the following.

```
ax1.spines['left'].set_visible(True)  
ax1.spines['bottom'].set_visible(True)
```

And then set the spine line widths:

```
ax1.spines['left'].set_linewidth(3)  
ax1.spines['bottom'].set_linewidth(3)
```

Here's the result:
[image: Plot]
Is there a more proper way to do what I want?

Comment: I used the same approach as you, i.e., first, turn down all four axes, and then show two of them.

Comment: @HanZhengzu I am not sure if Cartopy offers a more direct method to do this, but I really hope they have. I spend a couple of weeks on this with no avail because I have a really big plot in which if you zoom in to see each subplots, the spines are thicker than the colorbar width, which doesn't look good.