# How to hide axis lines but show ticks in a chart in Altair, while actively using "axis" parameter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, charts, altair

I am aware of using `axis=None` to hide axis lines. But when you have actively used `axis` to modify the graph, is it possible to keep just the ticks, but hide the axis lines for both X and Y axis?

For example, here is a graph I have where I'd like it to happen -

```py
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4], 'b':[2000,4000,6000,8000]})

alt.Chart(df).mark_trail().encode(
    x=alt.X('a:Q', axis=alt.Axis(titleFontSize=12, title='Time →', labelColor='#999999', titleColor='#999999', titleAlign='right', titleAnchor='end', titleY=-30)),
    y=alt.Y('b:Q', axis=alt.Axis(format="$s", tickCount=3, titleFontSize=12, title='Cost →', labelColor='#999999', titleColor='#999999', titleAnchor='end')),
    size=alt.Size('b:Q', legend=None)
).configure_view(strokeWidth=0).configure_axis(grid=False)
```

The output should look like the ticks in this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44525032/turn-off-axis-keep-ticks).
**Note:** The plot in that post has nothing to do with the demo provided here. its just for understanding purposes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Vega-Lite calls the axis line the *domain*. You can hide it by passing `domain=False` to the axis configuration:

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4], 'b':[2000,4000,6000,8000]})

alt.Chart(df).mark_trail().encode(
    x=alt.X('a:Q', axis=alt.Axis(titleFontSize=12, title='Time →', labelColor='#999999', titleColor='#999999', titleAlign='right', titleAnchor='end', titleY=-30)),
    y=alt.Y('b:Q', axis=alt.Axis(format="$s", tickCount=3, titleFontSize=12, title='Cost →', labelColor='#999999', titleColor='#999999', titleAnchor='end')),
    size=alt.Size('b:Q', legend=None)
).configure_view(strokeWidth=0).configure_axis(grid=False, domain=False)
```

[image]